# Error - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, stored-functions

I'm trying to create and use a function in a single block of code. The function works fine, but when I try to use a select statement below it oracle gives me an error. The select statement returns what I want when I run it in a separate block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TOT_PURCH_SF 
    (p_shopper_ID IN number)
    RETURN NUMBER 
    AS 
    lv_sum NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(TOTAL)
    into lv_sum
    from bb_basket;
  RETURN lv_sum;
END;


SELECT TOT_PURCH_SF(23) tot_purch
    FROM BB_SHOPPER
    WHERE idshopper = 23;
```

I expect the output to be 546.86, and it is when the select statement is run separately, but the error shows when I run it below the function.

Comment: the parameter `p_shopper_ID` is not used within the function.

Comment: Your function doesn't use the passed in shopper id, by the way

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=278cd353c053ef7b1f599ae4a10763bb). It works fine on both Oracle 11g and 18c.

Comment: You are missing a slash on a line by itself at the end of the function code and before the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using `sql-developer` or some other kind of `tool`.

First of all what is the requirement of using `SELECT` statement directly after `function` code?

`Functions` are stored code and you can call them from any where.

Now, to give answer of your question.

1. Simply select(cursor left click and drag) the last 3 lines (i.e. `select` statement) and execute them. It will work individually.
2. Use `slash` (`/`) after code of the `function` ends to make that as end point of the pl/sql code.

In your case what happens is your `tool` is not able to identify where the `function` code ends.

And you dont have to worry about such issues as `function` code is stored in metadata once you create them. And whenever you call that function, Oracle will use the code from metadata to execute its logic.

I would suggest to make total isolation between creation and usage of `function`. i.e. create function from one window and close that window once successfully created.

you can then execute only `select` statement in any if the tool windows.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you wanted was an [inline function in a WITH clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABJFIDC), rather than a separately declared one.

Setup:

```
create table bb_shopper
( idshopper integer primary key );

create table bb_basket
( idshopper references bb_shopper
, total     number );

insert all
    into bb_shopper values (23)
    into bb_basket values (23, 1)
    into bb_basket values (23, 2)
    into bb_basket values (23, 3)
select null from dual;
```

Demo:

```
with function tot_purch_sf 
        ( p_shopper_id in bb_shopper.idshopper%type )
        return number 
    as 
        lv_sum number;
    begin
        select sum(total) into lv_sum
        from   bb_basket
        where  idshopper = p_shopper_id;

        return lv_sum;
    end;
select tot_purch_sf(23) tot_purch
from   bb_shopper
where  idshopper = 23
/

 TOT_PURCH
----------
         6

1 row selected.
```

If this is what you want, it would be worth updating your question title to make it easier for others to find it.